# Is it more efficient to limit a union query before limiting the total results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

## Setup

I am joining several tables to filter e-mail addresses in an autocomplete from several sources. I only include 2 in this example for simplicity but I'm actually using 6 at the moment.

Using SQL Server 2008.

## Current Query

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM (
  SELECT
    ID AS id,
    LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS label,
    Email AS identifier,
    'person' AS source_type
  FROM Persons
  WHERE (LastName + ', ' + FirstName LIKE 'a%' OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE 'a%')
    AND DATALENGTH(Email) > 0 AND Email IS NOT NULL
UNION
  SELECT
    Company AS id,
    Name AS label,
    Email AS identifier,
    'company' AS source_type
  FROM Companies
  WHERE (Name LIKE 'a%')
    AND DATALENGTH(Email) > 0 AND Email IS NOT NULL
) temp ORDER BY label ASC
```

## Question

Would it be more efficient or more performant to pre-order & limit the union queries? Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM (
  SELECT TOP 20
    ID AS id,
    LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS label,
    Email AS identifier,
    'person' AS source_type
  FROM Persons
  WHERE (LastName + ', ' + FirstName LIKE 'a%' OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE 'a%')
    AND DATALENGTH(Email) > 0 AND Email IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC
UNION
  SELECT TOP 20
    ID AS id,
    Name AS label,
    Email AS identifier,
    'company' AS source_type
  FROM Companies
  WHERE (Name LIKE 'a%')
    AND DATALENGTH(Email) > 0 AND Email IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY Name ASC
) temp ORDER BY label ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely with `UNION`.

`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates -- this is either a hash-based or sort-based duplicate removal algorithm.  Either way, fewer records going in is faster.

The situation is a bit different with `UNION ALL`.  SQL Server is pretty good about pushing predicates down from the outer query into the inner subqueries.  However, sometimes the subqueries can take advantage of indexes (or even partitioning) and including logic in the subqueries makes it simpler for the optimizer to find such improvements.